# Cannot convert from pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I´m trying to convert **from** pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp **to** datetime.datetime but the change is **not saved**:

type(df_unix.loc[45,'LastLoginDate'])

> OUTPUT: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

type(df_unix.loc[45,'LastLoginDate'].to_pydatetime())

> OUTPUT: datetime.datetime

df_unix.loc[45,'LastLoginDate'] = df_unix.loc[i,'LastLoginDate'].to_pydatetime()

type(df_unix.loc[45,'LastLoginDate'])

```
OUTPUT: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Comment: please put a sample input of your dates, or at least a copy of your traceback

Comment: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have this date:

```
some_date = pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")
print(some_date)
Output: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

To transform it to datetime just do this:

```
some_date.to_pydatetime()
```

And you will get:

```
output: datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

You can't use `datetime.datetime(some_date)` because the constructor of the `datetime.datetime` class takes 3 int numbers:

One for the year, one for the month and one for the day.

Answer (score 0):

`df_unix.loc[45,'LastLoginDate']` returns a scalar value. pandas uses `Timestamp` for scalar values so the type is correct.

Run `df_unix.info()`. You should see the column type is still `datetime64[ns]`.

You are also assigning one value at location `45` using `to_pydatetime` which is used for returning the native Python datetime object. It would be an interesting result if this changed the type for the whole column.