# Pandas: convert string to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

How can I include `datetime`s into `pd.DataFrame`?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ['2002-02-02', '2002-02-03', '2002-02-04']})
df["b"] = df["a"].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d'))  # datetime.strptime returns datetime.datetime
print(datetime(2002, 2, 2) in df["b"])
```

outputs `False`.

Similarly,

```
f["c"] = df["b"].apply(lambda t: t.to_pydatetime())
print(datetime(2002, 2, 2) in df["c"])
```

outputs `False`.

Note that neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563488/cannot-convert-from-pandas-libs-tslibs-timestamps-timestamp-to-datetime-datetim) nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068004/pandas-convert-series-from-datetimestamp-to-datetime-datetime-object) works. Following any of those approaches, I end up with `Timestamp`s instead of `datetime`s in the data frame.

I am using Python 3.8.5 and Pandas 1.2.1.

Comment: `datetime(2002, 2, 2) in list(df['b'])`?

Comment: @Epsi95 True. However, that means that I have to convert this every time.

Comment: @Epsi95 But `datetime(2002, 2, 2) in list(pd.to_datetime(df['b']).unique())` is again `False`.

Comment: `datetime(2002, 2, 2) in list(pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df['b']).unique()))`

Comment: the title of the question confuses me; in `pandas` you'll want to work with the built-in datatype (datetime64 from `numpy`). Note that pandas will auto-convert Python standard lib datetime to it's built-in datatype. Only if you have a pd.Series of type datetime.date or datetime.time, the type won't be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can see after all your manipulations that all series of `datetime` obejcts are automatically converted to timestamps when added to the dataframe:

```
>>> df
            a          b          c
0  2002-02-02 2002-02-02 2002-02-02
1  2002-02-03 2002-02-03 2002-02-03
2  2002-02-04 2002-02-04 2002-02-04
>>> df.dtypes
a            object
b    datetime64[ns]
c    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I suggest you use the built-in pandas datetime handling, it’s definitely not much harder than python `datetime` objects:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(2002, 2, 2) in df['b'].to_list()
True
>>> df['b'].eq(pd.Timestamp(2002, 2, 2))
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
>>> df['b'].eq(pd.Timestamp(2002, 2, 2)).any()
True
```

Additionally this opens up a wealth of possibilities to further handle dates and times that you can’t do with python `datetime` objects.

For example you can compare directly `str` instead of building `Timestamp` objects:

```
>>> df['b'].eq('2002-02-02')
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```